# ng-repeat not rendering last two divs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the following code last but one div inside ng-repeat is not rendered at all and the last div is being thrown out of ng-repeat  I don know what's wrong with this code, please anyone find the bug here

```
<div class="col_xs12 no_side_padding">
    <div class="col_xs12 heading2 no_side_padding">
        <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
            Account Number
        </div>
        <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
            Account Name
        </div>
        <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
            Account Type
        </div>
        <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
            Bank Name
        </div>
        <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
            Category 
        </div>
        <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
            Manipulate
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_xs12 no_side_padding">
        <div class="col_xs12 no_side_padding datadiv" ng-repeat="account in Accounts">
            <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="account.isMarked" ng-checked=account.isMarked>
                <span ng-bind="account.accountNo"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle" ng-bind="account.accountName">

            </div>
            <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
                <span ng-if="account.accountType=='1'">Savings Bank(SB)</span>
                <span ng-if="account.accountType=='2'">Current Account(CA)</span>
                <span ng-if="account.accountType=='3'">Fixed Deposit(FD)</span>
                <span ng-if="account.accountType=='4'">Recurring Deposit(RD)</span>
                <span ng-if="account.accountType=='5'">Housing Loan(HL)</span>
                <span ng-if="account.accountType=='6'">Vehicle Loan(VL)</span>
            </div>  
            <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle" ng-bind="account.bankName">

            </div>
        </div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
        <span ng-show="account.category=='1'">Supplier</span>
        <span ng-show="account.category=='2'">Customer</span>
        <span ng-show="account.category=='3'">Employee</span>
        <span ng-show="account.category=='4'">Others</span>
    </div>
    <div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
        <a ng-click="editAccount(account)" ui-sref="dashboard.editaccount">Edit</a> | <a ng-click="deleteAccount(account)">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one `</div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">`? Its not a valid div. Also, you have 2 erroneous divs closed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Change `</div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">` to  `<div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have never noticed that thing though so silly

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as an answer here.

```
</div class="no_side_padding borderstyle">
```

isn't a valid div. Removing the forward slash will work. Also, you have 2 extra divs closed at the end of your code